# Forward undefined number of arguments to another function

Tags: php, function, arguments

I will explain the question with a simple function accepting any number of function

```
function abc() {
   $args = func_get_args();
   //Now lets use the first parameter in something...... In this case a simple echo
   echo $args[0];
   //Lets remove this first parameter 
   unset($args[0]); 

   //Now I want to send the remaining arguments to different function, in the same way as it received
   .. . ...... BUT NO IDEA HOW TO . ..................

   //tried doing something like this, for a work around
   $newargs = implode(",", $args); 
   //Call Another Function
   anotherFUnction($newargs); //This function is however a constructor function of a class
   // ^ This is regarded as one arguments, not mutliple arguments....

}
```

I hope the question is clear now, what is the work around for this situation?

## Update

I forgot to mention that the next function I am calling is a constructor class of another class.
Something like

```
$newclass = new class($newarguments);
```

Comment: Sending the remaining arguments as an array is not an acceptable solution. I want to send the argument as the same way as "arg[1], arg[2].. so on and so forth...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**for simple function calls**

use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/function.call-user-func-array.php), but **do not implode** the args, just pass the array of remaining args to `call_user_func_array`

```
call_user_func_array('anotherFunction', $args);
```

---

**for object creation**

use: [ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs](http://php.net/manual/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php)

```
$refClass = new ReflectionClass('yourClassName');
$obj = $refClass->newInstanceArgs($yourConstructorArgs);
```

or: [ReflectionClass::newinstance](http://www.php.net/manual/reflectionclass.newinstance.php)

```
$refClass = new ReflectionClass('yourClassName');
$obj = call_user_func_array(array($refClass, 'newInstance'), $yourConstructorArgs);
```

Comment: What if the next function is a constructor of a class?

Comment: @Starx See the added example.

Comment: For the object creation, which one is preferred solution, first one or the second

Comment: @Starx I'd go for the first one.